# How to give push notification in react-native app when data arrived from native in background?

Tags: react-native, push-notification, background

I send data native android and ıos to react-native. I give PushNotification when data arrived app in foreground. Data also send it from native when app in background. How to give PushNotification when react-native app in backgorund.

```js
import { DeviceEventEmitter } from 'react-native';
import PushNotification from 'react-native-push-notification'

componentWillMount: function() {
    DeviceEventEmitter.addListener('customEventName', function (e: Event) {
        PushNotification.localNotification({
            title: "My Notification Title", // (optional)
            message: "My Notification Message", // (required)
        });
    });
}
```